# Only run function if the elements are found on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run this code only if the elements are found on the page? This function runs great on my home page where the function is needed; however, on other pages, where the function is not needed, the console produces `cannot read property .top of undefined...` errors in the console because, I'm assuming, the elements aren't found on the page.

```
$('.play').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#music").offset().top - (
          $(window).width() < 450 ? 112 : 60
        )
    }, 500);
    $('.play').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.music-home').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `.length` property like `$("#music").length` if the value is 0 it means element doesn't exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($( "#music").length) {
    //Element exists
}
```

Comment: if ($( "#music").size()) {
    //Element exists
}
cuz cooler ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.play').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var len = $("#music").length;
    if(len){ 
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find element's `length` first before accessing it. 
Try Below code this will work for you on any page. As it will work only if `#music` element is found otherwise it won't.

```
$('.play').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#music").length > 0)
    {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#music").offset().top - (
          $(window).width() < 450 ? 112 : 60
         )
        }, 500);
         $('.play').fadeOut(function() {
         $('.music-home').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }
});
```